# Can't attach the allure report to the Jenkins email

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure

The Allure report is not attaching to the Jenkins email. I am using the Jenkins pipeline script and this is my script however this is the error i get in my email:

> Groovy Template file [allure-report.groovy] was not found in $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates.

Also I am not able to find `allure-report.groovy` in my computer

Here is my Jenkins pipeline, I am not sure how to include the template:

```
    pipeline {
        
        agent {
            label {
                label ""
                customWorkspace "/john/qa-end-to-end"
            }
        }
    
    
      tools {nodejs "node"}
    
      stages {
            stage('Checkout App') {
                steps {
                    dir("${env.HOME}/app") {
                    echo "Building.."
                    sh 'git reset --hard HEAD'
                    sh 'git clean -f -d'
                    sh 'git pull'
                    }
                }
            }
            
    
              stage('Starting Tests') {
                steps {
                    echo "Starting End to End Tests"
                    dir("${env.HOME}/qa-end-to-end/") {
                    sh './tests.sh'
                }
              }
            } 
    
        }
        
            post('Publish Report') {
              always {
                script {
                  allure([
                    includeProperties: false,
                    jdk: '',
                    properties: [],
                    reportBuildPolicy: 'ALWAYS',
                    results: [[path: '$WORKSPACE/${env.HOME}/app/target/allure-results']]
                  ])
                }
                
              
            }
            failure {
            emailext(
            attachmentsPattern: "$WORKSPACE/${env.HOME}/qa-end-to-end/allure-report/index.html", 
            body: '''${SCRIPT, template="allure-report.groovy"}''',
            subject: "Failure in End to End Tests -> Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", 
            from: "john@gmail.com",
            to: "mike@gmail.com"
            )
            }
            }
            
    }
```

Comment: Please show your Jenkins pipeline script how to send email

Comment: @yong, i added my pipeline. Can you please take a look at it again?. I am not sure how to include or mention the template in the pipeline script

Comment: From your script, i  think your issue comes from `post('Publish Report')`, please comment out the whole `post('Publish Report')` block and rerun job again.  The `allure` jenkins plugin is to generate Allure report and attach the report to the job not mail. Plugin description here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin/  and here is example https://ci.qameta.io/job/allure-plugin/job/master/ there is Sidebar link: Allure Report

Comment: @yong, sorry i posted the wrong one. Can you check my pipeline again please

Answer (score 1):

`$JENKINS_HOME/email-templates` is used to place email body template, generally when you install Jenkins plugin like `email`, it which includes some pre-defined templates and those templates will be extracted into `$JENKINS_HOME/email-templates` after plugin installed.

And when you use `send email` in job's Post Action, you can choose to use one of template of plugin and Jenkins will try to get the template from folder `$JENKINS_HOME/email-templates`

**If you want to use self template**, you need to put it into `$JENKINS_HOME/email-templates` too.

> Using custom scripts (those not packaged with email-ext) requires the cooperation of your Jenkins administrator. The steps are relatively simple:
>
> 1. Create the script/template. The name of the script end in the standard extension for the language (.groovy). The template can be named anything
> 2. Have your Jenkins administrator place the script inside $JENKINS_HOME\email-templates.
> 3. Use the script token with the template parameter equal to your template filename, or in addition the script parameter equal to the custom script name. For example, if the template filename is foobar.template, the email content would look like this ${SCRIPT, template="foobar.template"}.

[More detail](https://plugins.jenkins.io/email-ext/)

Comment: i added my pipeline. Can you please take a look at it again?. I am not sure how to include or mention the template in the pipeline script